# Run yarn in a different path

Tags: yarnpkg

Is there a way to specify a working directory for `yarn`? This would be different then the `--modules-folder` option. Specifically, I'm trying to run the `yarn install` command from a location outside of the package location.

Similar to `-C` in git

Answer (score 155, accepted):

`--cwd` is what you want.

(tested with yarn 1.3.2)

Comment: Official docs for this cli option: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/#toc-cwd

Answer (score 255):

You can use `--cwd` like so `yarn --cwd <path> <yarn command>`.
The order of arguments is important.

Example:

```
yarn --cwd ~/test_project/ dev
```

Because the following will **not** work:

```
yarn dev --cwd ~/test_project/
```

Comment: The equivalent for `npm` is `npm --prefix`

Comment: What does tilde mean? absolute path to root?

Comment: Oh, that's the Linux notation. It doesn't work for Windows obviously. Had to use the regular `cwd` notation (`./`) instead.

Comment: ~ is the absolute path to the current user, not specifically to root.

Comment: @adi518 It's not strictly true to call ~/whatever "Linux" notation; ~ is expanded by the shell you're using (almost always to the home directory of the current user - I don't know of shells that do something else, but they may exist), not by the operating system.  Linux has a much larger variety of shells than Windows does, too.  This tends to bite people who don't realize that the shell is the thing that understands ~, when they use it in non-shell environments.

Comment: How do I run the same on windows if the folder I want to run it is `client` in the main folder and I'm running this from `server` folder? @madav

Comment: @Akhila Maybe try using a full path to client instead of using the ~ for root.

Comment: @Akhila It's impossible to answer your question without knowing the relative location of the `client` and `server` folders.