# Use the command keyword in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Im trying to figure out how to properly use the `command` key word in a docker-compose.yml

Im trying to execute the following commands:

1. cd ./wait-for-it
2. wait-for-it.sh postgres:5432
3. cd
4. cd ./api
5. yarn start

I can structure it like this

```
command: ["./wait-for-it/wait-for-it.sh", "postgres:5432", "--", "yarn", "start"]
```

However I don't know how to cd into api before doing yarn

Any thoughts on how to structure the command properly?

Comment: Isn't the problem that you have a bare `cd` in the middle?

Comment: nop that brings me back to the home directory modifying to make clearer

Comment: Ah interesting, TIL. Do you know which *part* of that command fails then? What container is it running in? You could also try the `--cwd` flag to Yarn.

Comment: Further edit,  Its no currently failing im just missing a part of the command, executing the `yarn` from `./api` instead of the woking directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run yarn in a different path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46891622/run-yarn-in-a-different-path)

Comment: This doesnt seem to work unfotunately, I get an error saying the directory doesn't exist but running: `command: ["./wait-for-it/wait-for-it.sh", "postgres:5432", "--", "./api","yarn", "start"]` returns `./api is a directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute best way to manage complex startup commands like this is to (a) write them as shell scripts and (b) bake them into your Docker image.

For instance, I can reinterpret the startup procedure that you wrote as pseudocode like:

```
1. cd into the wait-for-it directory and run the wait-for-it script
2. Do the thing the container was originally going to do
```

I can translate that into a shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
(cd /app/wait-for-it && ./wait-for-it.sh "$DB_HOST_PORT")
exec "$@"
```

Then I can use that script as an `ENTRYPOINT` in my image.  It runs the `cd` command in a subshell so it returns back to the original directory on the next line; the `exec "$@"` line runs what was passed as a command.  The end of your `Dockerfile` would look like:

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh /app
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh

WORKDIR /app/api
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

Then I don't need to manually override these settings in the `docker-compose.yml` at all; the only thing I need to do is to provide the database location as an environment variable.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    environment:
      - DB_HOST_PORT=postgres:5432
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
```

If I wanted to run some other command:

```
docker-compose run myapp yarn migrate
```

It would still wait for the database to be available, but then run the alternate command.